# Lucene.net - singleton + queue = write.lock issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, iis, lucene

I have a strange problem. Here's the scenario:

I use Lucene.net, and I have the `IndexWriter` object as a singleton, because of the `write.lock` file. Also, only one thread is accessing to that object thanks to the `RabbitMQ`.

But I still get the error **System.IO.IOException: The process can not access the file "e:\MyIndex\write.lock" because it is being used by another process.**

I thought it can be caused by IIS pool recycle, as mentioned here https://medium.com/@ShamreshKhan/turning-off-iis-app-pool-overlap-recycle-6d2591faa312#.qnflhui4z but it didn't fix the problem. What else do I have to check what can cause the problem ?

My `IndexWirter` singleton:

```
public class Singletons
{
    private Singletons()
    {
        if (directoryMyTemp == null)
            directoryMyTemp = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(luceneMyDir));

        if (IndexWriter.IsLocked(directoryMyTemp))
            IndexWriter.Unlock(directoryMyTemp);

        //just to be sure
        lockFilePath = Path.Combine(luceneMyDir, IndexWriter.WRITE_LOCK_NAME);

        if (File.Exists(lockFilePath))
            File.Delete(lockFilePath);
    }

    private static readonly object singLock = new object();
    private static readonly Lazy<Singletons> lazy = new Lazy<Singletons>(() => new Singletons());

    private static readonly Lazy<IndexWriter> MyWriterLazy = new Lazy<IndexWriter>(() => new IndexWriter(MainInstance.MyDirectory, Workers.GetAnalyzer(), IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED));

    public static IndexWriter MyInstance
    {
        get
        {
            return MyWriterLazy.Value;
        }
    }

    public static Singletons MainInstance
    {
        get
        {
            return lazy.Value;  
        }
    }

    private static FSDirectory directoryMyTemp;
    public FSDirectory MyDirectory
    {
        get
        {
            return directoryMyTemp;
        }
    }
}
```

index rebuild:

```
Singletons.MyInstance.DeleteAll();

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    try
    {
        //document update
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Singletons.MyInstance.Rollback();
        throw;
    }
}

Singletons.MyInstance.Commit();
```

Comment: On which line exactly do you get this error? Also you are using Lazy in a wrong way and code inside your MainInstance getter may execute multiple times (maybe that is the reason even).

Comment: in a wrong way ? Hmm I use it the way it's described here http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: Not really - you (for some reason) check IsValueCreated and then act on result of this - it's not thread safe. At link you provided they just return lazy.Value - that is fine. To do it right you need to move everything from MainInstance getter to initializer of Lazy (where you now just do () => new Singletons()).

Comment: hmm or maybe put the whole MainInstance getter to the Singletons constructor ? See my edited post

Comment: Yes now it's fine. Maybe that even helped to resolve your problem, who knows. (you also don't need singLock any more by the way).

Comment: yeah I know that. Ok I'll check if this is gonna fix that issue, and I'll add the comment if it helps. Thanks !

Comment: looks like it fixed that issue, now it works (I hope it won't crash again ;))

Comment: Then maybe worth rolling back your question to first version so that I can post an answer for it (or you can post an answer yourself) - for people's future reference.

Comment: eh, I still get that error....